# Passing an object to function. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

gameI created the following "class":

```
function State(){
    this.board = [];
    for (i=0; i< 9; i++){
      var row = [];
      for (j=0; j< 9; j++){
        row.push(0);
      }
      this.board.push(row);
    }  
}
```

It has a method called nextEmptyCell:

```
State.prototype.nextEmptyCell = function(){
  ...
}
```

I created an instance of this class and passed it to another function.

```
game = new State();
function solveSudoku(game){
    var next = game.nextEmptyCell();
    ...
}
```

On the following line: `var next = game.nextEmptyCell();`  I receive an error saying:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextEmptyCell' of undefined".

I don't understand why 'game' is undefined and how to fix this error.
Link to the full code: jsfiddle.net/py6kv7ps/5

P.S. Is there a better way of using JS as OOP?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `var next = game.nextEmptyCell();`? (I.e. `game` instead of `state`.)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made mistake while typing the question. It supposed to be game.nextEmptyCell(). However, that is not the problem.

Comment: @Yhlas Next time pass your code in jsfiddle, right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue comes from `solveSudoku()`, you are calling it recursively without passing an argument. Thats why you are getting error.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextEmptyCell' of
>   undefined".

```
function solveSudoku(game) {  
      if (solveSudoku(ADD game OBJECT HERE)) {
        return game;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `game.nextEmptyCell()`, not `state.nextEmptyCell()`. There is no variable named `state` anywhere in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your parameter `game` shadows the glbal variable `game` of the same name. The global variable `game = new State();` has the correct value. So you can pass it to your method call to use the correct value of game within the method `solveSudoku()`

```js
function State(){
    this.board = [];
  
    for (i=0; i< 9; i++){
      var row = [];
      for (j=0; j< 9; j++){
        row.push(0);
      }
      this.board.push(row);
    }  
}

State.prototype.nextEmptyCell = function(){
  console.log('egvse gtrs');
  document.write('egvse gtrs');
};

var game = new State();
function solveSudoku(game){
    var next = game.nextEmptyCell();
} 

solveSudoku(game);
```

Comment: This code is clearly working. However when I do exact same thing on my full code it still gives me the same error as before.